# Custom fulfillment server based on user id

Tags: actions-on-google

I have an use case where each user must be answered by a specific fulfillment server. How can I use a different webhook URL address based on the id of the user that is talking to my agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a pretty odd use case.

In short - you can't. The best you'd be able to do is to create a proxy server webhook that gets the request from Google, determines the user and the correct location, and forwards the request to that location, then gets the response back from that location and forwards it as a reply back to Google.

Comment: The fulfillment server runs on a raspberry pi, that is in charge to read the house status or execute some actions to provide it's answers to actions on Google. The proxy idea seems like the only feasible option available by now, but the complexity and expected delay is a no go for me.